# Unable to register a tenant with X.509 based authentication in Hono

Tags: eclipse-hono

I am following [this guide](https://blog.bosch-si.com/developer/x-509-based-device-authentication-in-eclipse-hono/) in order to authenticate devices with certificates, but when i run the following command i get `404 NOT FOUND` (i am using the Hono sandbox):

```
curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Expect:' --data-binary @tenant.json https://hono.eclipse.org:28443/tenant
```

I also tried replacing `hono.eclipse.org` with `hono.eclipseprojects.io` since i read that the domain name will be deprecated.

I was wondering if the guide is up to date or something changed on the new releases of Hono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, Hono's example registry (as used by the sandbox) implements and exposes the [Device Registry Management API](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/api/management/) now. The tenant management endpoint URL to post to in order to create a tenant is

[https://hono.eclipseprojects.io:28443/v1/tenants/{your_desired_tenant_id}](https://hono.eclipseprojects.io:28443/v1/tenants/%7Byour_desired_tenant_id%7D)

Also make sure to check the payload format with the API spec.

You might want to take a look at [Hono's Getting Started](https://www.eclipse.org/hono/getting-started/) guide which also illustrates how to register a tenant, device and credentials.